# Over 9000, or: Karma perks on (C)SE

Tags: support, reputation

Actually, over 10000 :-)

I remembered I got some editing privileges on CSE when going over whatnot - can someone point me to a list? Are the numbers always the same on all Stack Exchange sites or varying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations!

The list is [here](/help/privileges). Chess Stack Exchange still uses the privilege levels of a beta site, which cap at 5k instead of 25k. You get the [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, normally awarded at 10k, at [2k already](/help/privileges/moderator-tools). A complete overview can be found on Meta Stack Exchange: [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/295232)

We're [not in beta anymore](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/631/7297) but that post says we "retain beta reputation levels". Only once we get a custom design those privilege levels *may* change (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/295232), bottom paragraph), but it depends on whether the community can support it or not. Right now, IMHO we're fine with the current levels.

Comment: THX for the detailed answer (which confirmed my suspicion that my question wasn't SO trivial that I could have easily googled around the SE FAQ myself - I probably wouldn't have found the linked Meta SE question).