# Does this site also work like codegolf/puzzling and support posing chess problems to other members?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Is that a valid usage of this stack?

If not yet, has it been considered?

Comment: If you want to ask such a problem (IIRC it has been done in the past), it's probably good to link to [that answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/577/7297) - it seems to have reasonable support from the community (+7/-1) - there's not much activity here on Meta.